# Multiple records from database in ASP.NET(C#)

Tags: asp.net

I want to fetch multiple records from database using stored procedure. I want to call that procedure from my ASPX application. How it will be possible ??

Any thing that I am trying is as follow:

Oracle Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_DDO
(
  TCODE IN VARCHAR2  
, DDOCODE_var OUT VARCHAR2  
) AS
BEGIN
  select ddocode into ddocode_var from ddo;
END GET_DDO;
```

My .CS Code:

```
 myconnection.ConnectionString = conString;
        using (myconnection)
        {
            myconnection.Open();          
            myadapter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("Get_DDO", myconnection);
            myadapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            myadapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("TCode", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = treasuryCode;
            myadapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("DDOCOde",OleDbType.Varchar).Direction=ParameterDirection.Output;
            myadapter.Fill(mydataset);            

            myconnection.Close();

            return mydataset;
        }
```

Comment: Post the error you're getting?

Answer (score 2):

You can write multiple select statements in Stored procedure e.g.

```
Select * from Table1

Select * from Table2
```

later from database layer you can use DataAdapter to get the values in DataSet  e.g.

```
dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
```

you can get both the recordset in two data tables of dataSet i.e.

```
dataSet.DataTables[0] // record from Table1

dataSet.DataTables[1] // record from Table2
```

sorry for the typo mistakes if found.

Comment: But I want to use stored procedure not individual query. Thanks.

Comment: you can use stored procedure or query , doesn't matter only you have to change Command Type.